# why there is an llegal string offset and how to resolve it?

Tags: php

I have an error about my fuction on this line:

```
$FILE_LIST[$key]['name'] = str_replace('.' . $ext, '', $result);

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'
```

I tried different way but i don't find the solution.
I look other post like [Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324791/warning-illegal-string-offset-name)
but it do not resolve the problem (or I fogot something).

the function

```
public function getFiles($source_folder, $filename, $ext = 'php') {
  if(is_dir( $source_folder)) {
    $FILES = glob($source_folder . $filename . '.' . $ext);
    $FILE_LIST[] = '';

    if (is_array($FILES)) {
      foreach($FILES as $key => $file) {
        $result = str_replace($source_folder, '', $file);
        $name = str_replace('.' . $ext, '', $result);

        if (!empty($name)) {
          $FILE_LIST[$key]['name'] = $name;
        }
      }
    }

    if (is_array($FILE_LIST)) {
      return $FILE_LIST;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try defining `$FILE_LIST` as `$FILE_LIST[] = []` instead of as a string.

Comment: Should rather be `$FILE_LIST = [];` if this is supposed to be the general initialization of that variable as an array.

Comment: I can't see the line you get the error on in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (!empty($name)) {
  $FILE_LIST[$key]['name'] = $name;
}
```

to this:

```
if (!empty($name)) {
   $FILE_LIST[$key] = Array();
   $FILE_LIST[$key]['name'] = $name;
}
```